# store data in xml file in php with loop

Tags: php, xml

I am new in programming and want help.
I want to save 2 variable's value in 4 tags and that group of tags will print as many times as user want in .xml file.
how can i do this ? Is there any loop or recursion function ?

my code is this:

```
$variable1='abc';
$variable2='xyz';

$xml->channel->item = ""; 
$xml->channel->item->addChild('title', $variable1);
$xml->channel->item->addChild('link', $variable2);
$xml->channel->item->addChild('description', $variable1);
```

out put is this :

```
<item>
      <title>4</title>
      <link>4</link>
      <description>4</description>
</item>
```

I want to print this item tag with its sub tags as many time as user want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object, then add "item" as a child and set that result to a variable. Then you can add more children (title, link, description) to that child.

```
$data = [
    [
        'title' => 'Made up Title',
        'link' => 'http://madeupwebsite.com',
        'description' => 'Hello world'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Made up Title 2',
        'link' => 'http://madeupwebsite2.com',
        'description' => 'Hello world2'
    ]
];

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

foreach ($data as $item) {

    $child = $xml->addChild('item');

    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $child->addChild($key, $value);
    }

}

print($xml->asXML());
```

Comment: i got this error:   Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\test.php on line 177

Comment: on line number 177 i have this statement:   $xml->channel->item->addChild('title', $tty);

Comment: Because you must add `item` as a child node of `channel` instead of setting it to an empty string as you've done (`$xml->channel->item = ""`). Call `$xml->channel->addChild('item')` and then you will be able to call `addChild` on `$xml->channel->item`

Comment: Happy to hear it! Would you mind marking the answer as correct? Thanks